# How to find column name with column index in DataGridView?

Tags: c#, datagridview

I want to find column name in `DataGridView`.
I have column index. How can I find it.

`dGVTransGrid.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex`: I want it's column name.

Plz help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 53):

There may be a better way, but why don't you just ask the DataGridView what the column with that index is called?

```
int columnIndex = dGVTransGrid.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex;
string columnName = dGVTransGrid.Columns[columnIndex].Name;
```

Comment: if (dGVTransGrid.CurrentCell!=null && dGVTransGrid.CurrentCell.OwningColumn.Name.ToString() == "Rate")

Comment: @Nagendra: Why are you calling ToString() on Name, when it's already a string?

Comment: Because now he's sure 200% he has that name extracted.

Answer (score 18):

Found an easier way, on a single line.

```
[datagrid].CurrentCell.OwningColumn.Name
```

hope it helps.

br,
Eric Estrada Gomez

Answer (score 3):

If you want it dynamic on the cell clicked then you can get it from the event

```
private void dataGridViewName_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    String columnName = this.dataGridViewName.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for (var i = 0; i < DataGridView.ColumnCount; i++)
var name = DataGridView.Columns[i].HeaderText;
```

this is a simple way of doing it.

Answer (score 1):

In a single row of code

```
String name = dataGridView1.Columns[dataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex].Name;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I'm quite late to answer this,
I was going through the same requirement and I found this query. I tried the below code snippet and it worked for me:

Since you said you know index, you can use the below snippet.
If you already have an index number, then you can directly fetch the column name based on that index.

```
Dim index As Integer = 0 
Dim grid As DataGridView
Dim colName As String = grid.ColumnFields(index).HeaderText
```

If you don't know the index number, you can use the below snippet.

```
Dim colIndex As Integer = 0
Dim colName As String = "" 
Dim grid As DataGridView
For index As Integer = 0 To grid.ColumnFields.Length - 1
    If grid.ColumnFields(index).HeaderText = colName Then
        colIndex = index
        Exit For
    End If
Next
```

Answer (score -1):

It may be helps you:

```
String s = dataGridView1.Columns[Index].HeaderText;
```

Comment: This is not correct - column Names and Header Text do not have to be the same.