# Insert from datagridview to database

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

Hi i would like to ask is there any way to insert the column names automatically?

```
for (int i = 0; i < ADODB.Rows.Count; i++) 
 {
  StrQuery = @ "INSERT INTO tableName VALUES (" + ADODB.Rows[i].Cells["ColumnName"] + ", " + ADODB.Rows[i].Cells["ColumnName"] + ");";
  comm.CommandText = StrQuery;
  comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
 }
```

Comment: from datagridview?

Comment: do your column names in the datagridview match the column names in your table?=!

Comment: Yes from datagridview @Znaneswar

Comment: Yes it matches @MongZhu

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to find column name with column index in DataGridView,c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3819240/how-to-find-column-name-with-column-index-in-datagridview-c)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I didn't understand wrong, what about this?

```
string[] columnNames = dataGridView1.Columns.Cast<DataGridViewColumn>()
                                            .Select(x => x.HeaderText).ToArray();
// get column names to string array
string joinedArray = string.Join(",", columnNames);
// set them into string seperating with ,
string sql = "INSERT INTO tableName VALUES (" + joinedArray + ")";
```

Hope helps,

Comment: HI @Berkay i tried using your code but it seems like they have problem even though the database and the file has the same name...

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[i].Text // i is column number
```

or

```
dataGridView1.Rows.HeaderRow.Cells[i].Text  // i is column number
```